# Performing segue if condition is met

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

You can see from the photo the set up of my UI.
The objective is when the button is pressed if a number is greater than 9 the label on the first viewcontroller to change to "number is greater than 9" and if its smaller than 9 the segue should be triggered and the label on the secondView should change to "number is greater than 9..
This is what i have done so far, but when the segue is triggered the label on the secondView does not change..

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var labelFirst: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberEntered: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String!, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
            var number: Int? {
                get{
                    return Int(numberEntered.text!)
                }

            }

            if number>9 {
                labelFirst.text="number is greater than 9"
                return false}

            else {

        return true
                func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
                    if  (segue.identifier=="segue"){

                        let destinationVC:secondView = segue.destinationViewController as! secondView
                        destinationVC.outputText="number is smaller than 9"

                    }
                    }
        }
     }
}
```

the segue is connected to the button and directs to the second view.

secondView:

```
import UIKit

class secondView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var outputText=String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        label.text=outputText
    }

}
```

[ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLrB5.png)

Comment: I've voted to close this question as [unclear what you're asking](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: hi, i have rephrased, is it still unclear?

Comment: where is the photo ?

Comment: does the segue is showing second screen?

Comment: please  click on the ui(link) at the very end

Comment: can you show the code of secondVC

Comment: yes when the button is pushed and if the bool is true the segue should be triggered and display the secondview

Comment: i have added it to my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prepareForSegue method is in the wrong place , it should be outside the shouldPerfomSegue method and marked with override.

Comment: Thanks!! Could you explain why it had to go outside shouldPerformSegue?

Comment: When you declare a function inside another function you can use it only there so you can name it whatever you want and the compiler won't complain even if it's named the same as other inherited function , the same is true for properties. So what you did is creating a local function that is just named as the function that you wanted to use but not the actual inherited function that you intended to use .

Comment: so the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier function only checks if the segue should be performed or not BUT not actually perform the segue? and in case of a true the prepareForSegue comes and performs the segue?

Comment: Yes , the shouldPerfomSegue just like it's named should contain logic that determines whether the segue should be performed ( in your case the greater than 9 logic) , the prepareForSegue just like it's named should contain preparations just before the segue is performed ( pass data to the destination controller or some other things) , what actually triggers the segue and calls those functions is the fact that you connected a segue in the IB or of course you can call it programmatically instead if you want.

Comment: I have one more question, i am trying to implement textFieldShouldReturn function but as i dont have my button hooked to an IBAction how do i manage to make the keyboard dissapear and use the Go button on the keyboard instead of the Button on the storyboard to trigger the segue?

Comment: Go to your storyboard , select the segue , give it an identifier in the Attributes inspector and now you can use performSegueWithIdentifier method to call the segue programmatically.

Comment: I have already done that! But i dont know how to implement the func textFieldShouldReturn...

Comment: 1. Set your textfield delegate. 2. in textFieldShouldReturn call the segue you want to perform using performSegueWithIdentifier and return true.

Comment: i managed to get the segue triggered via return button as per your advice but it overrides the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier. i.e the segue is always called, while if you see above the segue should be called only if the number is smaller than 9

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not updating on the second screen is because you are doing it inside viewDidLoad. That only happens once. Move the code to viewWillAppear.

```
import UIKit

class secondView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var outputText=String()

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        label.text = outputText
    }
}
```